# rearranging data from multiple data files

Tags: python, perl, bash, awk, fortran

I have 40,000 data files. Each file contains 1445 lines of floating numbers in single column. Now I need to rearrange the data in different order.

The first number from each data file need to be collected and dumped in a new file (lets say abc1.dat). This particular file (abc1.dat) will contain 40,000 numbers.

And the second number from each data file need to be extracted and dumped in a another new file (let's say abc2.dat). This new file also will be containing 40,000 numbers. But only second numbers from each data file.

At the end of this operation I supposed have 1445 files (abc1.dat, abc2.dat,...abc40000.dat) and each contains 40,000 data.

How this can be achieved ? (Using Linux Ubuntu 11.10 - 64 bit)

Appreciate any help. Advance Thanks.

Comment: OS? (just to make sure it isn't something with a 256-file-descriptor process limit)

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 11.10 (64 bit)

Comment: `"I suppose I have 1445 files (abc1.dat, abc2.dat, ... abc40000.dat)"` -- abc1445.dat?

Comment: @george: Presumably he's willing to accept an answer in any language he can understand, which includes Fortran along with Python, Perl, Bash, and Awk. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What have you thought of so far?

Comment: @Vijay - I don't have a 11.10 machine at hand, but I think that opening 40000 files at once with a 64bit kernel shouldn't be a problem (that's the kernel I have on my machine, although I am typing from a 12.04 machine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

40,000 * 1445 is not so many, it should fit into memory. So, in Perl (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @nums;
# Reading:
for my $file (0 .. 40_000) {
    open my $IN, '<', "file-$file" or die $!;
    while (<$IN>) {
        chomp;
        $nums[$file][$.-1] = $_;
    }
}

# Writing:
for my $line (0 .. 1444) {
    open my $OUT, '>', "abc$line.dat" or die $!;
    for my $file (0 .. 40_000) {
        print $OUT $nums[$file][$line], "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If we assign a scalar that was only ever used in numeric context, we can save considerable memory (roughly 25%, depending on the length of the numbers). I/O produces strings, which we do not need. → `push @{$nums[$file]}, 0+$_;`

Comment: @amon You also risk losing precision, as floats are chomped up by the processor.

Comment: @ysth `perl -lwe'$_="3.123123122010234511"; print; print 0+$_;'` For me this prints 3.123123122010234511 and 3.12312312201023. I am not familiar with the details, I just know to be careful about floating point precision.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this perl code and it is running fine. I shall try others too.

Answer (score 3):

If you can open all 1445 output files at once, this is pretty easy:

```
paths = ['abc{}.dat'.format(i) for i in range(1445)]
files = [open(path, 'w') for path in paths]
for inpath in ('input{}.dat'.format(i) for i in range(40000)):
    with infile as open(inpath, 'r') as infile:
        for linenum, line in enumerate(infile):
            files[linenum].write(line)
for f in files:
    f.close()
```

If you can fit everything into memory (it sounds like this should be about 0.5-5.0 GB of data, which may be fine for a 64-bit machine with 8GB of RAM…), you can do it this way:

```
data = [[] for _ in range(1445)]
for inpath in ('input{}.dat'.format(i) for i in range(40000)):
    with infile as open(inpath, 'r') as infile:
        for linenum, line in enumerate(infile):
            data[linenum].append(line)
for i, contents in enumerate(data):
    with open('abc{}.dat'.format(i), 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(''.join(contents)
```

If neither of these is appropriate, you may want some kind of hybrid. For example, if you can do 250 files at once, do 6 batches, and skip over `batchnum`*250 lines in each `infile`.

If the batch solution is too slow, at the end of each batch in each file, stash `infile.tell()`, and when you come back to the file again, use `infile.seek()` to get back there. Something like this:

```
seekpoints = [0 for _ in range(40000)]
for batch in range(6):
    start = batch * 250
    stop = min(start + 250, 1445)
    paths = ['abc{}.dat'.format(i) for i in range(start, stop)]
    files = [open(path, 'w') for path in paths]
    for infilenum, inpath in enumerate('input{}.dat'.format(i) for i in range(40000)):
        with infile as open(inpath, 'r') as infile:
            infile.seek(seekpoints[infilenum])
            for linenum, line in enumerate(infile):
                files[linenum].write(line)
            seekpoints[infilenum] = infile.tell()
    for f in files:
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get away with a one-liner like this:

```
perl -nwe 'open my $fh, ">>", "abc${.}.dat" or die $!; 
           print $fh $_; close ARGV if eof;' input*.dat
```

It will open a new output file for appending for each line of the input file. The output file will be named according to the current line number of the input file. At the end we need to explicitly close the ARGV file handle to reset the line number variable `$.`.

You can control the order of the input files with your glob, or with perl if you prefer. I opted for a generic glob, as you did not specify that the lines should be in a particular order.

Efficiency-wise, I do not think it will be excessively time-consuming to open a new file for each line, as perl is rather fast at file operations.

Note that you do not need to close the output file handle, as it is automatically closed when it goes out of scope. Also note that it will not care about your file size.

Answer (score 2):

bash:

```
cat file1 file2 ... file40000 | split -n r/1445 -d - outputprefix
```

Assuming all files have exactly 1445 lines, writes to outputprefix0000, outputprefix0001, ... outputprefix1444.

A little slow, but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Once the files were created, this took about 4 minutes to run and used 3.6GB of RAM on my laptop. If you have 8GB of RAM in your machine, it should be no problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import random

NUMFILES = 40000
NUMLINES = 1445

# create test files
for i in range(1, NUMFILES + 1):
    with open('abc%s.dat' % i, 'w') as f:
        for j in range(NUMLINES):
            f.write('%f\n' % random.random())

data = []

# load all data into memory
for i in range(1, NUMFILES + 1):
    print i
    with open('abc%s.dat' % i) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        data.append(lines)

# write it back out
for j in range(len(data[0])):
    with open('new_abc%s.dat' % (j + 1), 'w') as f:
        for i in range(len(data)):
            f.write(data[i][j])
```

I’ve kept everything as strings to avoid precision errors in deserializing and then reserializing floating-point numbers.

---

Do you need something faster and less resource-intensive that you can run regularly, or is this a one-off conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, because of the [fortran] tag, a belated example in Fortran. It opens files one by one and stores all of the data in memory.

```
program copy
  implicit none

  character(1024) :: filename
  integer :: i, unit, infiles, outfiles
  parameter (infiles = 40000, outfiles = 1445)
  real :: data(infiles, outfiles)

  do i = 1, infiles
    write(filename, '("path/to/file", I0, ".dat")') i
    open(newunit = unit, file = filename, action = 'read')
    read(unit, *) data(i,:)
    close(unit)
  enddo

  do i = 1, outfiles
    write(filename, '("path/to/abc", I0, ".dat")') i
    open(newunit = unit, file = filename, action = 'write')
    write(unit, '(G0)') data(:,i)
    close(unit)
  enddo
end program
```

Note: it will probably be quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

In awk, it's very simple:

```
awk '{print >> "abc" FNR ".dat}' files*
```

I'm not sure if awk will be able to handle 40,000 open file handles though.

Comment: Well, `awk` shouldn't have any problem with 40K handles… but the OS might. As far as I can tell, nobody in the comments or answers has yet tested with Ubuntu 11, but my guess from what people _have_ tested is that you'll just have to change the soft ulimit before running this, which is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below works on solaris.

```
nawk '{x="abc"FNR".txt";print $1>x}' file1 file2
```

you can anyhow do :

```
nawk '{x="abc"FNR".txt";print $1>x}' file*
```

for referring all 40k files